# && in while loop not returning first function

Tags: php, while-loop

The below code only returning the second echo and if I remove `&& $fetch_desc = mysql_fetch_array($select_desc)` then first echo is working else only second echo is displaying.

Any clue how to handle this? Thanks.

```
$select_name = mysql_query("query1");
$select_desc = mysql_query("query2");
      while($fetch_name = mysql_fetch_array($select_name) && $fetch_desc = mysql_fetch_array($select_desc)){
      echo $fetch_name['field_value'];
      echo $fetch_desc['field_value'];
      }
```

Comment: You may want to reconsider your question title

Comment: You should probably provide more details in the code snippet, such as the query. Provide a table structure perhaps as well... This sounds like something you should be either (A) querying multiple columns, or (B) using a JOIN.. Nonetheless, you shouldn't be using any `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Comment: Probably a boolean short-circuit biting you in the rump. If the entire while() condition can be determined by only executing ONE of the fetch operations, then the other fetch won't be performed.

Comment: What @HalfCrazed said, mysqli provides better security from SQL injections through pre-initialised queries!

Comment: Crikey, do people still use `mysql_*` functions these days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
while(($fetch_name = mysql_fetch_array($select_name)) && ($fetch_desc = mysql_fetch_array($select_desc))){
```

It might be that it's getting the conditions muddled, parenthesis stop that from happening.